# Python (How to update xml file without creating new file)

Tags: python, linux, shell, unix, python-2.6

I need to change the value of element( DB_CONNECT_STRING) in an xml file without creating new file using python or shall scripts.

## Xml file content

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
<!-- Database server details -->
<DB_CONNECT_STRING>(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=abc)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=cdb)))</DB_CONNECT_STRING>
</properties>
```

## updated xml file

```
------
<properties>
--------
<DB_CONNECT_STRING>(new data)</DB_CONNECT_STRING>
-------
</properties>
```

Comment: What research have you done. Hint: https://docs.python.org/release/2.6.9/

Answer (score 1):

`sed -i` is what you're looking for.

In your case, it should be

```
sed -i 's#<DB_CONNECT_STRING>.*</DB_CONNECT_STRING>#<DB_CONNECT_STRING>(new data)</DB_CONNECT_STRING>#' <here_is_your_file>
```

Comment: @Ban, I'd like to use `os.system('sed xxx')` because of its simplicity. see https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) for simple XML edits:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u /properties/DB_CONNECT_STRING -v "new value" file.xml
```

If the output looks OK, use `xmlstarlet --inplace ...` to save back to the file.